# Implement batchMerge() in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I need to "upsert" a List of items.

```
class Item {
 private UUID id;
 private UUID anotherId;
 private List<String> things;
 ...
}
```

If an item's `id` and `anotherId` is already existing, other values should be replaced by the new item. If it's not, item should be inserted as new record.

I came across JOOQ's `batchMerge` and I thought it is similar to "upsert". Unfortunately there are few documentation on the internet since this is a fairly new method by JOOQ as of writing.

I tried

```
List<ItemRecord> items = ... //built from context.newRecord(ITEM) then added to a list
context.batchMerge(items).execute();
```

thinking it will automatically get the updated fields. There is no update in the values if row is already existing. It does insert a new record if it's not yet existing.

I came across this documentation of `merge` but I do not know how to translate it to `batchMerge`. https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/merge-statement/

I am fairly new to SQL and JOOQ. I am using PostgreSQL as database.

Comment: I see the <sql> tag, but is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Comment: You find everything you want to know in the API doc: https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchMerge(java.util.Collection)

Comment: [Insert ... On Duplicate Key](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.15/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/) may help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOOQ's `batchMerge()` works as expected with Postgres.

The problem was not actually with JOOQ. A service that calls the repo method for batchMerge is marked `@Transactional`. It's a Spring annotation which has a rollback feature. That is why it appears it doesn't persist to the database. I marked it as `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = CustomException.class)` to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of jOOQ 3.15), batch executions in jOOQ cannot fetch generated IDs, see: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3327

However, since you're using `UUID` types for your IDs (as opposed to sequence generated ones), do you even need the server to generate the IDs? You might as well generate them already in the client and insert them with the rest.